# Is it possible to manipulate the action bar from a separate fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, actionbarsherlock, menuitem

I'm relatively new to action bars and I'm using the actionBarSherlock library.
I'm aware that actionbar's work best when you have actions that occur often and are easily accessible.

**Background:**

My action bar currently works by enabling a home button and onCreateOptionsMenu that inflates a menu with a calendar menu item (not visible) and settings menu item.

I have a main activity that calls multiple fragments like FragA, FragB, FragC.

**Question:**

Is it possibly to somehow manipulate my menu items **from** my fragments, or at least when they are about to be called in such a way, that I can "show" the calendar menu item and handle calls to it?

Here's what I have so far: **actionbar_view.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="30dp"
android:orientation="horizontal" >
<Button
    android:id="@+id/b1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:text="Stuff" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Here's how I use the homeButton:

```
public void onResume() 
{
    super.onResume();

    actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
    actionBar.setIcon(R.drawable.icon_tsn);...
}
```

The fragment I want to work with just extends SherlockFragment..
Any help is appreciated...

Comment: Your action item must have title set `android:title=""`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possibly to somehow manipulate my menu items from my fragments, or at least when they are about to be called in such a way, that I can "show" the calendar menu item and handle calls to it?

Your fragment is welcome to call `setHasOptionsMenu(true)` (e.g., from `onCreateView()`), at which point it will be called with `onCreateOptionsMenu()` and `onOptionsItemSelected()`, much like activities are. If the fragment is visible, its action bar items will appear, otherwise they will be removed.

Hence, the typical pattern is to have the activity define action bar items that are valid regardless of what fragments are visible, and to have fragments define action bar items that are specific to them.

Comment: Hi CommonsWare,
I tried what you suggested but I'm getting a NullPointerException at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.toString(MenuItemImpl.java:496). Do you know why this is happening?

Comment: Using this https://github.com/JakeWharton/ActionBarSherlock/issues/902, (exact error I get), I just commented out the log causing the crash. but now my nothing is happening when I click on the icon...

Comment: @AminaKhalique: As was noted on that issue, and as Neoh mentioned in a comment elsewhere, your `<item>` element in your menu resource needs an `android:title` attribute, even if you are not using a title.

Comment: Hi CommonsWare - I ended up adding title like suggested by Neoh, however it only worked when I manipulated my main activities onOptionsSelected(), it didn't work in the fragments onOptionsSelected()... But it is working now.